# ¿How to use or add two or more components within a tab section?

Tags: html, vue.js

I have this **tab** system, which works perfectly for me. I am learning VueJs. I have a concern
regarding components and/or templates. My concern is:

Using any **tab** windows as an example,how do I add two **components** inside a **tab**,I mean
one of its windows or sections.

Any help,please?

```
This is my codepen:
```

https://codepen.io/luis-tavarez/pen/dyOeRwO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be worth checking out Vue's [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Using the layout you already have in place, you could add additional components to a tab by doing the following. Let's assume the new component will be named `Custom`.

1. Add an additional `router-view` to your HTML:

```
<section class="mainBody">
  <router-view name="header"><button>asaaasas</button></router-view>
  <router-view name="content"></router-view>
  <router-view name="custom"></router-view>
</section>
```

2. Add a new template block to Home, for example above line 43 where you've described the `Header` template:

```
const Custom = {
  template: `
    <section class="content">
      <div>
        <h1>Here is your new custom component</h1>
      </div>
    </secion>
  `
};
```

3. Update **Components** in your **Routes** description:

```
{
  path: "/three",
  name: 'three',
  components: {
    header: Header,
    content: contentThree,
    custom: Custom
  },
  props: {
    header: true,
    content: false
  }
},
```

And here it is rendered:
[image]

Comment: Ohhh!I did not want to know anything about frameworks,but i'm getting in love with this.Lol.Thanks man!